# MySQL reference result from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-update

This is what i am doing

```
update t1 set x=a,y=b where a and b are obtained from (select query here)
```

1. I know the select query
2. The select query returns multiple results which are the same
3. When I use group by or distinct query execution slows down considerably
4. a and b are forward references so mysql reports an error
5. I want to set a equal to the value obtained in the first row and b equal to the value obtained in the first row for the respective columns, to avoid group by. I don't know how to refer to the first result from the select query.

How can i achieve all this?

Comment: You need to show us a little more detial than that. Show us the query that you currently have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT` specifies the number of rows to return from the beginning of the result set:

`SELECT * FROM t2 LIMIT 1;`     # Retrieve 1st row

`LIMIT` in your case is applied in the subquery in your `from` clause.

These linsk can help you out with `update` that uses a subquery:

[Update with Subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245106/update-with-subquery)

[Subqueries in MySQL, Part 1](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking for something like...

```
update T1, (select Sub1.a, Sub1.b from YourSubQueryTable Sub1 where ... ) SubResult
  set T1.a = SubResult.a,
      T1.b = SubResult.b
  where
      Some T1.Criteria To be applied
```